# HMGET with an array in lua-resty-redis

Tags: lua, redis

I want to replace this command:

```
red:hmget('item', 'item:1', 'item:2')
```

With something like:

```
local test = {'item:1', 'item:2'}
red:hmget('item', test)
```

But, I'm getting an error `(string expected, got table)` when I try this.  How can I format this in Lua for Redis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending upon which version of Lua you're using, you'll want to make use of `unpack`.

- **[Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack)** `red:hmget('item', unpack(test))`
- **[Lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack)** `red:hmget('item', table.unpack(test))`

`unpack` is a function which *unravels* an array-style table as if you were using it like a set of arguments. It is somewhat similar to a splat operator that you might find in other languages.

```
> =unpack{'item:1', 'item:2'}
item:1  item:2
```